# Convert a whole android package to jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i know we can convert a java class file into a jar file , but i want to know , is there any way to convert a whole Android Package into a jar file or another format , so i can use them in another project ?

and if with any way we can convert it , and the main app has some permissions , are they added to second app or i must add them in second app manifest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Android Archive Library i.e. an AAR file (*.aar) if you make  your project a library. As far as I know a JAR file cannot contain all the Android specific components of the project. You can find a very brief JAR/AAR comparison [in this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915619/android-archive-library-aar-vs-standard-jar).

You can have a look at these tutorials by [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html) and [Android By Code](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/building-an-aar-library-in-android-studio/) for creating such a library and you may find relevant Stackoverflow discussions with the ["aar" tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aar). But as this is a rather new feature and support in Android Studio (or Eclipse ADT) has improved from version to version some of the older discussion might not be up-to-date anymore.

The permissions specified in the library's manifest will apply to the library code even in the app. that is using the library. [Commonsware](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/01/15/library-authors-you-cant-always-get-what-you-want.html) has explained the manifest aspect in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must go in Eclipse, to File -> Export -> Java (jar file) -> and there you select the package you want to export as a .jar file.

Concerning your second question, you must add the permissions again to the second application.