# Class not found exception after adding library project

Tags: android

I have created a library project as .jar file and try to use it in another project. But I am getting Class not found exception while using it.I added all the activities from the library in my manifest file and its all permission. But still getting same error.

Here is my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="in.moovo.moovobroker.Activity.Mainactivity"/>
</application>
```

My error stack trace here :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lin/moovo/moovobroker/R$layout;
at in.moovo.moovobroker.Activity.Mainactivity.onCreate(Mainactivity.java:85)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6072)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "in.moovo.moovobroker.R$layout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/in.moovo.moovobrokerappmapview-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
at in.moovo.moovobroker.Activity.Mainactivity.onCreate(Mainactivity.java:85) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6072) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2315) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:155) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1323) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5298) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745) 
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: in.moovo.moovobroker.R$layout
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: have you tired rebuilding the project.. it fixed for me when i had the same issue.. and also try restarting android studio..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is not for Activity. This is for `in/moovo/moovobroker/R$layout` which you used into `in.moovo.moovobroker.Activity.Mainactivity`.

The way you are using is not correct way. When you decide to use jar file, the classes which are into jar, should not have dependency on any external resources.

Correct way is to use aar file. Read how to [Create aar file in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309950/create-aar-file-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

jar files contain only code! No activities can be found in your jar file. If you wish to use the activity resource files, you should use aar file instead.

Specifically: the 'aar' bundle is the binary distribution of an Android Library Project.

The file extension is .aar, and the maven artifact type should be aar as well, but the file itself a simple zip file with the following entries:

```
/AndroidManifest.xml (mandatory)
/classes.jar (mandatory)
/res/ (mandatory)
/R.txt (mandatory)
/assets/ (optional)
/libs/*.jar (optional)
/jni/<abi>/*.so (optional)
/proguard.txt (optional)
/lint.jar (optional)
```

These entries are directly at the root of the zip file.
See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915619/android-archive-library-aar-vs-standard-jar) for details.