# How can I bundle a .so file in a jar?

Tags: java, android, jar, java-native-interface

I'm currently working on a java library (binding) which uses some own written native code. This native code is compiled as a `.so` file for multiple architectures (arm-v7, i686, x86-64, etc).

I know in android you have to create a folder called `jniLibs` with subfolders for each architecture containing the proper `.so` file. Then with an `Android.mk` file and `System.loadLibrary` I can include these files into my code.

However, I have no clue how to include these `.so` files in a normal java project/library. I have read online that `System.loadLibrary` only works for looking through normal files (and not necessarily project files).

Comment: So your single jar is meant to "cross-deploy" across both Android and regular desktop/server Java environments? That's ... ambitious-sounding.

Comment: @Max : Please check this : http://blog.guillaumeagis.eu/setup-andengine-with-android-studio/

Comment: This somewhat contradicts the "compile once, run everywhere" idea of Java. Anyway, that is not related to C. Shared libraries are no way C-specific.

Comment: That is my goal, yes @unwind

Comment: @AndiGeeky This post is for android, which I got it working for already. My question is aimed more towards java itself.

Comment: @Max : Oh.. then sorry buddy..!!

Comment: OK, now it sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the problem you are trying to solve (X)? Attempting to solve it with a single distribution (Y) sounds hard and has a low payoff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have anything other than code in an android `.jar` file, however, you can have resources in an `.aar` file.

[Android Archive Library (aar) vs standard jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23916544/360211)

You will find that the `.aar` for your library is the redistributable/reusable compiled version of your library.

Comment: Thankyou for this article, it sure helped me understand the difference between a `.jar` and `.aar` more. However, is there a work-around on how I can deliver my native code with a `.jar` in a user-friendly way?

Comment: You must use aar files. Doesn't get more user friendly than that. They replace jar files, so it's still a single file to distribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as how `SWT` did it -- extract the library files from your `.jar` file to user's **home directory** (so you are sure you have access to write in it) manually by java code.
You can check the source code of `org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library`, method `extract()`.