# In Android Studio, is there a way to search a word within jar, aar, and maven imported libraries?

Tags: android, android-studio, search, jar, aar

Sometimes within the library I need to search a method name or a method that deals with what I am looking for.

In Android Studio, is there a way to search a word within jar, aar, and maven imported libraries?

It doesn't have to be using Android Studio, is there a tool which I can search words within jar, aar, maven imported libraries?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Android Studio, for searching something within the imported libraries, you can try :

Open Edit menu

Select "Find" -> "Find Usage Settings" and select the Scope as "Project and Libraries"

OR

Select "Find" -> "Find in path" and select "Scope" scope specifying this as "Project and Libraries"

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I still cannot find string from jar in Android Studio 3.2.1 @Neh

Comment: "Custom" is now "Scope"

Answer (score 6):

Find in Path (**Ctrl + Shift + F**)

[image]

Comment: this works 2022

Answer (score 1):

**Search text in .jar .aar**

As a variant you can

1. find an archive with classes (Project View -> Reveal in Finder)
2. open with Java Decompiler (e.g. [JD-GUI](http://java-decompiler.github.io/))
3. Save all sources (File -> Save all sources)
4. Use a text finder

[[JAR vs AAR]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65789668/4770877)

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio has **Java Decompiler IntelliJ Plugin** (apparently it's JD-GUI in Android Studio)

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the headache and install the JadX plugin on Android Studio.

Restart your IDE then hit "Tools" -> "Jadx GUI" -> navigate to the directory where your .aar or .jar is and hit enter.