# How to convert an .aar file into a .jar

Tags: android, eclipse, jar, ibm-mobilefirst

To work with Eclipse IDE in for an IBM MobileFirst Platform project, I need to convert an .aar file into a .jar. I tried to extract the classes.jar file, but it is practically empty, with none class. I mean, at the Android SDK, the *extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4* libraries only have classes until 24.1 version, from there all the versions bellow, only have the empty classes.jar file. So, what can I do with the classes in these versions?

Trying to clarify a little bit this topic, this question helped me:

[Android Archive Library (aar) vs standard jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915619/android-archive-library-aar-vs-standard-jar)

Some one knows a process to turn this Android Archive file into a Java Archive file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to convert an .aar file into a .jar

By definition, an AAR is not a JAR and cannot necessarily be "converted" into a JAR.

Frequently, if the artifact is distributed as an AAR, instead of a JAR, that is because there is more than just Java code that is part of the artifact.

> I mean, at the Android SDK, the extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4 libraries only have classes until 24.1 version

Correct. Since then, `support-v4` has merely been a container for transitive dependencies. You will see a list of them in the POM file adjacent to the artifact.

For example, the `25.3.1` POM file shows all of the artifacts that will be pulled in when you use `support-v4` in an AAR-artifact-aware IDE (Android Studio, IntelliJ IDEA, etc.):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
  <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
  <version>25.3.1</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-compat</artifactId>
      <version>25.3.1</version>
      <type>aar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-media-compat</artifactId>
      <version>25.3.1</version>
      <type>aar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-core-utils</artifactId>
      <version>25.3.1</version>
      <type>aar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-core-ui</artifactId>
      <version>25.3.1</version>
      <type>aar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.support</groupId>
      <artifactId>support-fragment</artifactId>
      <version>25.3.1</version>
      <type>aar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

As you can see from the `<type>` elements, most of those transitive dependencies themselves are AARs.

Sometimes, the AAR does not contain much other than a JAR.
For example, the `25.3.1` edition of `support-core-utils` — one of the AARs that `support-v4` pulls in — has nothing of importance other than its `classes.jar` that I can see.

However, other AARs have things beyond the JAR. For example, `support-compat` and `support-media-compat` have AIDL files. Other AARs — such as `appcompat-v7` — have resources or assets. If you try just using the JAR out of the AAR, and you try using a class that expects those resources or AIDL files or whatever to exist, your app will crash.

You can attempt to convert an AAR into an old-style Eclipse library project. As the saying goes, your mileage may vary. Plus, I have no idea if IBM MobileFirst supports library projects.