# Opened project in android studio and all packages/symbols are marked as incorrect

Tags: android-studio, import, package

I am trying to contribute to my first open source project but after forking and cloning from the repo, all files are marked as an error.

[Sample error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eC9N.png)

This is after selecting a source folder.

[Current project source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEbXl.png)

Under package it says: package name does not correspond to filepath

... but I have this

[misnamed packages?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0Fc4.png)

Comment: Please copy paste the text of your "sample error" so that others may be able to search for and find a solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Android studio isn't picking up those libraries.

IME there are 2 ways of importing these (I have only had success with the first):

1) copy the source parallel to your own (ie example.com)

2a) include the jar in a libs folder and tell AS to look out for it. (right click will typically provide a good option that I can't recall)

2b) because Android can struggle (ie I couldn't do it, though inroads may have been made since) with importing jars, you may need to use AAR's (android library packages, [Android Archive Library (aar) vs standard jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915619/android-archive-library-aar-vs-standard-jar))

However, because this is an open source project, this should all be handled auto-magically for you via the gradle scripts included in the distro.