# How to use aar maven dependency in scala/java project

Tags: java, scala, maven, gradle, aar

The scala project that I am working on requires a maven dependency but is in aar type instead of jar.

How do I use the classes inside the aar in my scala project as I cannot import any of the classes from the aar in my project.

Is there a way to convert the aar to jar while downloading the dependency and building the project.

Comment: You tagged maven and gradle. Which one is your build tool for your Scala project?!

Comment: Also what is this dependency? I've never seen AAR files before..

Comment: @GaëlJ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23915619/android-archive-library-aar-vs-standard-jar