# How to import multi-module SDK project by exposing its core module only

Tags: android, maven, gradle, module, dependencies

I am developing a project which should work as an Android sdk, the project includes:

- an app module for demo
- a module called mainSdkModule
- other minor modules that are used in the mainSdkModule (lets say moduleA and moduleB)

the `mainSdkModule` imports `moduleA` and `moduleB` this way:

```
implementation project(':moduleA')
implementation project(':moduleB')
```

I am publishing the whole project as an SDK that I want to use in another app project.
To test the integration of this SDK I am temporarily publishing it to my local maven folder. What happens is that when I import the sdk into the app project, the build fails with the following error:

```
Could not find sdk-main-package:moduleA:unspecified.
Required by:
    project :mainSdkModule > sdk-main-package:core:1.0.0
```

I could avoid this error by publishing each module as an indipendent library but I need to keep them internal without exposing them.

Is it normal that the app project asks for a dependency that isn't even supposed to be visible by other projects besides the sdk one?
How can I include `moduleA` and `moduleB` inside the core and grant access to them for those who import the SDK without exposing these internal modules on maven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules A and B are declared as external dependencies and will be referenced as such in the pom.xml file. Something like this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>sdk-main-package</groupId>
   <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
   <version>unspecified</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

What you want is to create a **fat jar** or a **fat aar**. A fat jar/aar is a jar/aar file that also includes the dependencies (instead of referencing them as external dependencies). I don't know if your SDK needs to be a jar file or an aar file and if you don't know either then you can find out the difference e.g. here: [Android Archive Library (aar) vs standard jar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23915619/534471).

If you need a **fat jar** then you can use the `Shadow` plugin: https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction.

If you need a **fat aar** then you can e.g. use this: https://medium.com/android-news/android-fat-aar-from-gradle-892038facc87. There are other solutions but I haven't personally tested any of them so don't know which ones really work. If you google `fat aar` you'll get plenty of hits and I hope one of them solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio
Do This:
**1-File -> Project Structure

2-select Dependencies from left menu

3-select app you see + and - in top middle of screen, click on +

4-select Module Dependency and tick your mainSdkModule and add it to your app module

5-select mainSdkModule and click + and tick ModuleA and ModuleB

6-apply and build your project**